# Using selenium chrome browser in background (not headless mode)?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I want to run my python script which uses selenium to do some work. I need to test the code repeatedly and need to use the terminal as well. Thus the chrome window bugs me when it opens up in the foreground everytime. Also, I can't use the headless mode since my script crashes.

Is there any solution for this ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can minimize window after selenium started

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.minimize_window
driver.get("your_pages")
```